# Script Works but Permissions Denied

Tags: batch-file, permissions

I used one of my co-workers scripts for user back-ups and re-wrote it to better suit the company needs. I had his permission and he now uses this script also.Here is what I came up with:

```
rem This script was put together by A Domain Admin
rem using a previous script by another Domain Admin
rem for the purpose of backing up users files on
rem their PC's to a network share using the 
rem RoboCopy function. It will copy their Desktop,
rem My Documents, and Favorites folders.
rem Remember that an initial folder with each users 
rem domain name will need to be made on the network 
rem share in order to have this work.

rem This portion builds the different files needed
rem on the specified server to place the backed up
rem files in
@mkdir \\DC-FS1\users\%username%\%computername%\ 
@mkdir \\DC-FS1\users\%username%\%computername%\Desktop\ 
@mkdir \\DC-FS1\users\%username%\%computername%\My_Documents\ 
@mkdir \\DC-FS1\users\%username%\%computername%\Favorites\ 

rem This prints to the screen all the user will 
rem need to know before the backup happens
@cls
@echo TriTech Software Systems - :User.Backup:
@echo For support, please call IS at ext. 7499
@echo --------------------------------------------------------------
@echo Press any key to start the synchronization of your "Desktop",
@echo "Favorites", and "My Documents" folders to a network server.
@echo --------------------------------------------------------------
@echo This will NOT include any virtual machines, music files, or 
@echo video files located in these areas. It will also remove
@echo from the backup any objects that are no longer in the backed 
@echo up area. This will also NOT include any folders not in the
@echo 3 specified. 
@pause

rem This is the actual backup processes. I added a 
rem pause at the end so the user could check to see 
rem if any errors had occured during the backup if  
rem they would like
robocopy "C:\users\%username%\Desktop" \\DC-FS1\f$\backups\users\%username%\%computername%\Desktop\ /s /xf *.avi *.iso *.mp3 *.m4a *.m4b *.m4p *.m4v *.mp4 *.ova *.vmdk *.vmem *.vmss *.vhd *.wma *.wmv *.pst *.bak *.epub *.ipa *.mobi *.mov *.rdp /purge
robocopy "C:\users\%username%\My Documents" \\DC-FS1\f$\backups\users\%username%\%computername%\My_Documents\ /s /xf *.avi *.iso *.mp3 *.m4a *.m4b *.m4p *.m4v *.mp4 *.ova *.vmdk *.vmem *.vmss *.vhd *.wma *.wmv *.pst *.bak *.epub *.ipa *.mobi *.mov *.rdp /purge
robocopy "C:\users\%username%\Favorites" \\DC-FS1\f$\backups\users\%username%\%computername%\Favorites\ /s /xf *.avi *.iso *.mp3 *.m4a *.m4b *.m4p *.m4v *.mp4 *.ova *.vmdk *.vmem *.vmss *.vhd *.wma *.wmv *.pst *.bak *.epub *.ipa *.mobi *.mov *.rdp /purge
@pause
```

The script works great except one thing. When a user, other than a domain admin, runs the script on his\her PC after each robocopy it states "Access is denied" All users have been given everything less than Full Access to their respective folders on this network share. Does anyone have any idea why I would still be getting an "Access is denied"? I have been pouring over all permissions even giving the users Full permissions at one point to try and solve this and still nothing

Comment: I believe this has to do with you using the Administrative Share versus an actual server share.  Domain admins will have no problems but normal accounts will.  I think this article describes it correctly. https://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/08/access-denied-trying-to-connect-to-administrative-shares-on-windows-7/

Comment: Do you think that if I pulled the F$ out of the robocopy that would fix my issue then? Could I just shorten that part to only the folders in the network share they would have permissions to?

Comment: Did you create a server share named **backups** with the appropriate file and share permissions for each user?

Comment: Yes I did. All permissions seem to be set up correctly

Comment: The users don't have any permissions to anything in front of the "Users" folder though. Could this be the problem area

Comment: There's a lot of code; it would be much easier to read if you post only the portion of interest and leave out all the `rem` and `@echo` lines...

Comment: This is not really that hard to test if you have a standard domain user to test with.  This network/server 101 class.  Troubleshoot it by doing everything manually first with a standard user.  Where does it fail?  Do the make directory commands work? Do the Robcopy commands work?  The paths you use for the make directory command is not the same as the Robocopy command.  You are creating directories in a share called USERS but your robocopy command is copying to a share named BACKUPS and to a sub folder named users.

Comment: @Squashman Yes I just tested this with a standard network user and I believe I have success. All I did was pull out the \F$\backups part of each of the robocopy strings and it worked. Thank you very much for the help. Not sure why I didn't think of this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the script as administrator.

Tomer.

Comment: This did work if i wanted to run it as administrator. Thank you for your reply. But I want to have the standard network users run this from their desktop and not as an administrator.

Comment: @EddieStuder, I am not sure why you marked this as the answer to your question if it was not the answer you needed.

Comment: @Squashman He did provide a solution though. I'm still fairly new to stackoverflow. I was hoping you would post an answer so I could mark that as the answer.

Comment: @EddieStuder, all I did was guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @Squashman yes but that is waht gave me the answer I was looking for. Tomer gave me an answer you gave me the answer I wanted through direction. I really appreciate all the help you gave me. And you helped me learn along the way